A weaker property than $2$-transitivity
Let us define a half $2$-transitive action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ as an action with the two following properties :
1° the operation is transitive;
2° for every distinct elements $x, y$ in $X$, for every distinct elements $z, t$ in $X$, there is an element $g$ in $G$ such that $\{gx, gy\} = \{z, t\}$;
[$ \mathbf{Edit}$ : 3° $ \ \vert X \vert \geq 2 $.]
(This has something to do with $2$-homogenous actions, but I don't know exactly what conditions are required for an action to be called $2$-homogenous.)
We can note that if $X$ has at least $3$ elements, 2° implies 1°.
Clearly, a $2$-transitive action is a half $2$-transitive action.
$\mathbf{Edit}$ (27. 06. 2024)
If $G$ is a (finite or infinite) $2$-group, the reciprocal is true, in other words :
Let $G$ be a $2$-group, with a half $2$-transitive action on a set $X$; then this action is $2$-transitive.
Proof. Since the operation is transitive and $ \ \vert X \vert \geq 2 $, the operation is not trivial. Thus, the image of $G$ in $S_{X}$ is a nontrivial 2-group, so it has an element of order 2. Such an element is a permutation of order $2$, so there is a $2$-cycle in its decomposition, so there is an element $g$ in G and two distinct elements $x$ and $y$ such that $gx = gy$ and $gy = gx$. From this and the fact that the action is half 2-transitive, it is easy to conclude that the action is $2$-transitive.
My question is : do you know other types of groups such that a half $2$-transitive action of such a group is necessarily $2$-transitive ? Thanks in advance.

For bracket in LaTex use antislash in front of the bracket (as if the bracket { was a command like log or sin))

Thanks, EDX, but I do so and it doesn't work, in any case in the draft.

In math mod you should I think you omit it ?, I proposed an edit

Action with this property are called $3$-homogeneous.

@Derek Holt What you say here doesn't seem to correpond with what you said on the page "group actions transitive on certain subsets?"

Yes OK the definition of a 2-homogenerous action of $G$ on $X$ does not require transitivity, but it is easy to show a 2-homogeneous action is transitive when $|X| >2$, so you might just as well consider 2-homogeneous actions. For finite $X$, the 2-homogeneous actions that are not 2-transitive were classified by Livingston and Wagner (1965) and Kantor (1972).

Thanks for this information, @Derek Holt. My question came into my mind when I read Burnside's proof of the non-simplicity of groups of order 756. Perhaps I will ask a question about this proof.
